# I've created a new console in win32 window-only app, console is created but nothing gets print on it

Tags: c++, winapi, console

this code is compiled with `-mwindows` under gcc , there is no winapi error message.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, LPTSTR, int nCmdShow) {
  AllocConsole();
  printf("%s\n", "sample text");
  return 0;
}
```

Result is that console is black empty, no text, no error message.

Comment: You probably need top "open" the `stdout` to `"CON:"` (or something like that).

Comment: Well I tried many options, everything boil to this, as the code has no effect. So I posted the simplest example where behavior occurs.

Comment: How about just changing to console subsystem? Then you don't have to mind the console youurself...

Comment: Yea, but is this some kind of bug ? On whose part ? GCC, Windows, ale all windows version affected ? Or maybe is this misunderstanding from my side. If this is a bug that of course bummer, so that's why I ask.

Comment: Exactly what have you tried when you say "I have tried many options". `freopen("CONOUT$", "wb", stdout);` one of them? Unfortunately, I can't check it, as I have no windows on my Linux machine.

Comment: well, that works, I've tried something similar copied from a website, but there looks like was an error and I checked out that option, well thanks ! - found it, my code was : `freopen( "CON", "w", stdout ) `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
freopen("CONOUT$", "wb", stdout);
```

to reopen the `stdout` after you have created the console. If you plan on using it for input too, then you need:

```
freopen("CONIN$", "rb", stdin);
```

and stderr may need opening too:

```
freopen("CONOUT$", "wb", stderr);
```